# ADO.NET Data Services - propagate changes across tracked lists?

Tags: entity-framework, silverlight-3.0, wcf-data-services

So here is the situation. I am using ADP.NET Data Services 1.5 CTP2 with Silverlight 3. My EF data model is (in short) like this:

```
CmsProfile
      Id
      Name

CmsEvent
      Id
      Title

CmsProfileEventLink
      Id
      ProfileId
      EventId
```

So there is a many <-> many relationship between people and events. When I load the events within silverlight, I do it this way:

```
private void AsyncLoadEventsKickoff()
{
    DataServiceQuery<CmsEvent> theQuery = dashboardService
        .CmsEvents
        .Expand("CmsProfileEventLinks")
        .AddQueryOption("$orderby", "Title");

    theQuery.BeginExecute(
        delegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                () =>
                {
                    DataServiceQuery<CmsEvent> query = 
                        asyncResult.AsyncState as DataServiceQuery<CmsEvent>;
                    if (query != null)
                    {
                        //create a tracked DataServiceCollection from the 
                        //result of the asynchronous query.
                        events = DataServiceCollection
                            .CreateTracked<CmsEvent>(dashboardService,
                                query.EndExecute(asyncResult));

                        AsyncLoadTracker();
                    }
                }
            );
        },
        theQuery
    );
}
```

You will notice that I cannot get `Expand()` to actually drop the next level and get me the event link details. It will only really tell me if there ARE event link records or not.

I put all the events into a grid (`SelectionGrid`), and when you click one, I want to load ANOTHER grid (`EventsGrid`) with the people that are related to this event. I do this by loading the grid with `CmsProfileEventLink` objects and then drilling down on the `DataMemberPath` to the profile name. In theory, this allows the grid to add new links for me - when a row is added I give it an `Id`, and set the `CmsEvent` to the current event, take the user input for the `Profile` and blammo - new linked record.

In a perfect world I could just set `peopleGrid.ItemsSource = EventsGrid.Selecteditem.CmsPeopleEventLinks` and the whole thing would work as expected. However since the expansion doesn't got that deep, I can't.

As a workaround I have loaded all the `CmsProfileEventLinks` the same way into a "links" variable. So when you select a event I do this (ugly, ugly, ugly) to show the profiles...

```
private void Sync_EventsGrid()
{
    var item = SelectionGrid.SelectedItem as CmsEvent;

    if (item.CmsEventProfileLinks != null)
    {
        DataServiceCollection<CmsEventProfileLink> x = 
            DataServiceCollection
                .CreateTracked<CmsEventProfileLink>(
                     dashboardService, 
                     links.Where(p => p.CmsEvent == item));

        EventsGrid.ItemsSource = x;
    }
}
```

The problem is... that if a change is made within `EventsGrid` it does NOT propagate back to links context, even though they both share a `DataService` context. The net result? if you select a different event and come back, the `EventsGrid` does NOT show the recently added record. If you refresh the application, forcing it to re-read links from the database? it picks it up.

So I need any of the following...

1. A way to do the 2 level expansion
   of the `CmsEvent` record on initial
   load so I can simply pass its links
   property to the second grid
   (preserving the context)
2. A better way to get a filtered
   view of "links" that does NOT spawn
   an independant context that doesnt
   update
3. A way to notify the "links"
   object that it should refresh,
   preferably without forcing it to go
   all the way back to the server via a
   async call - since the data clearly
   has been updated in the local
   context.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop over the expanded property and call `LoadProperty` on each one to expand its children, like so:

```
DataServiceQuery<CmsEvent> query 
                         = asyncResult.AsyncState as DataServiceQuery<CmsEvent>;
if (query != null)
{
    //create a tracked DataServiceCollection from the 
    //result of the asynchronous query.
    events = DataServiceCollection.CreateTracked<CmsEvent>(dashboardService,
                                                 query.EndExecute(asyncResult));
    AsyncLoadTracker();

    foreach(var link in events.SelectMany(e=> e.CmsProfileEventLink))
    {
         dashboardService.LoadProperty(link, "CmsPeopleEventLinks");
    }
}
```